# Why does my SNES console hooked up to flat panel monitor show incorrect colors?

Tags: monitor, snes, chrono-trigger, pal

When I try to play Chrono Trigger (US) on my European SNES (with the help of a converter cartridge called 'UA universal adaptor expert version') that's hooked up to a scart-to-hdmi converter device that's hooked up to my PC monitor, I get completely messed up colors on the screen. It's like I am seeing 4-bit colors; red, blue and green ugly all over.
Just like when your SCART cable is improperly inserted on your old tv (remember?).
However that's not the problem because the SCART is inserted firmly into the converter box.

To troubleshoot, I tried hooking up my SNES console to my regular old TV through SCART only and there was no problem there. The colors displayed perfectly.

So what is causing the colors to be displayed incorrectly on my flat panel monitor?
Is it the scart-to-hdmi box that's doing this? Is it the monitor that's doing this?
My monitor works perfectly with everything else (xbox, PC, ..) even with the same HDMI cable used. From what I read, that converter box 'automatically' switches between PAL and NTSC signal.

Here is my setup:

- My PC monitor:
  http://www.asus.com/Display/LCD_Monitors/VK246H/
- My scart-to-hdmi converter upscaler box:
  http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SCART-HDMI-1080p-HD-UPSCALER-Converter-Adapter-Sky-Wii-VHS-STB-DVD-HDTV-/300614927083
- My SNES:
  PAL European
- Cabling:
  I'm using a gold plated HDMI 3-star cable I think (regular HD resolution).

Comment: Did you try a different SCART cable? Inserting it firmly doesn't help if its broken =p

Comment: I have good news and less good news: The good news is that I followed the method most Youtubers did. I hooked up my SNES SCART cable into the SCART-IN-2 of my standalone DVD recorder and I hooked the SCART-OUT-1 of that DVD recorder up to the SCART-to-HDMI converter. Now everything works fine except that the picture is a tad blurry. Nothing to worry about though. It's negligible. The less good news is that now I have to use that bulky DVD recorder in order to play. Do you have a better suggestion so I won't need my DVD recorder in order to convert the picture into something playable?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it's the converter box - there's got to be some pretty sophisticated electronics in there in order to convert the signals, and I've found that there can be a lot of quality loss unless you pay an arm and a leg for one from a reputable seller & manufacturer.

Comment: That pesky little device cost me $140. I've seen its embedded chipset. Quite sophisticated indeed. It does the conversion of a regular DVD SCART fine, just not for the SNES. It has probably something to do with the fact that SNES SCART cable internally has different capacitators.